# XNA - Collision never happens

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating a game in XNA and I need a collision detection logic:

```
public Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)playerShipPos.X, (int)playerShipPos.Y, frameWidth, frameHeight);

this.boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)meteorPosPub.X, (int)meteorPosPub.Y, (int)meteorTexture.Width, (int)meteorTexture.Height);

for (int i = meteorList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    meteorGenerator meteor = new meteorGenerator(Vector2.Zero);

    if (meteorList[i].meteorPosPub.Y > 664)
    {
        meteorList.RemoveAt(i);
        if (meteor.boundingBox.Intersects(playerShip.boundingBox))
        {
            meteorList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to achive this effect: if the player ship touches the meteor the meteor is hides and is removed from the list but nothing happens, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = meteorList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    meteorGenerator meteor = new meteorGenerator(Vector2.Zero);//you are creating new list meteors every frame, this is ridiculous 

    if (meteorList[i].meteorPosPub.Y > 664)
    {
        meteorList.RemoveAt(i);//if you are removing a position from a list, not destroying the meteor
        if (meteor.boundingBox.Intersects(playerShip.boundingBox))
        {
            meteorList.RemoveAt(i);//you already did this, this conditional is unnecessary
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what it is you are doing, but this is what I would do.

1.Let the player and meteor inherit from a class with the properties a solid object would have.

2. Add those to a list with unique IDs based on the object type.
3. Every frame, check for IDs (this gives you extra control on what you want to collide with what).
4. Proceed to check for collisions, in case you want to remove an element, just remove it from the list and destroy it.